# How do I declare a function like this?

Tags: java, methods, chaining, method-chaining

How can I declare a function like `damagePlayer` below in Java?

```
player.getPlayer1().damagePlayer(50);
```

I already know that we have to declare something like this to get it:

```
ServerPlayer player = new ServerPlayer();
```

But, how do we put the second function (`GetPlayer()`) in the first place? I'm learning Java, and this would be an awesome way to save code.

Comment: What function are you trying to declare? getPlayer1 or damagePlayer? Are you only trying to declare or to implement?

Comment: Im trying to ask how do I even declare this function in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
player.getPlayer1().damagePlayer(50);
```

damagePlayer(50) would be written as a method of the type that getPlayer1() returns.  So implement your damagePlayer(int x) class in the class whose instance player.getPlayer1() returns.

so if getPlayer1() returns an object of the type (or class ) Foo , you would write the damagePlayer method in the Foo class.

eg.

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.doThis().doThat(25) ;

class Bar{
  public Foo doThis() {
    Foo foo=new Foo();
    //do some thing using foo

    return foo;
  }
}

class Foo() {

  void doThat(int number){
    // can do anything using parameter number and return anything
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare **methods** on class named `Player`, that will work.

```
public Player getPlayer(){
    return this;
}

public void damagePlayer(int damage){
    ...
}
```

It's just one way.

Answer is - first method must return object which is an instance of the Player class, where method `damagePlayer` is.

Comment: The OP want to getPlayer1. It sounds like he wants to hold an array of players and return the first. Maybe.

Comment: Edit: What Benjy said.